# Checking date against date range in Python

Tags: python, datetime, date, time, boolean

I have a date variable: `2011-01-15` and I would like to get a boolean back if said date is within 3 days from TODAY. Im not quite sure how to construct this in Python. Im only dealing with date, not datetime.

My working example is a "grace period". A user logs into my site and if the grace period is within 3 days of today, additional scripts, etc. are omitted for that user.

I know you can do some fancy/complex things in Python's date module(s) but Im not sure where to look.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

In Python to check a range you can use `a <= x <= b`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> margin = datetime.timedelta(days = 3)

>>> today - margin <= datetime.date(2011, 1, 15) <= today + margin
True
```

Comment: Point given to Mark Byers. I agree, more readable but equally valid to Thomas's answer. Thank you both. I've added both methods to my Diary. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 12):

Subtracting two `date` objects gives you a `timedelta` object, which you can compare to other `timedelta` objects.

For example:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> date(2011, 1, 15) - date.today()
datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> date(2011, 1, 15) - date.today() < timedelta(days = 3)
True
>>> date(2011, 1, 18) - date.today() < timedelta(days = 3)
False
```

As to "where to look": the official [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) is excellent.

Comment: I tried this in Python 3.1.3 and get a "SyntaxError: invalid token" when using 01 for January vs. using 1 for January.

Still giving you #1 though...:)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Python 2 will interpret that as octal, but they dropped this syntax in Python 3 because it was confusing. I always write my dates in octal, don't you? ;)

Comment: I'm new to learning Python, so I don't know what I do. I welcome all direction! Thus why I come to SO daily.

Answer (score 9):

Others have already more than adequately answered, so no need to vote on this answer.
(Uses technique shown in Mark Byers' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695609/checking-date-against-date-range-in-python/4695663#4695663); +1 to him).

```
import datetime as dt

def within_days_from_today(the_date, num_days=7):
    '''
        return True if date between today and `num_days` from today
        return False otherwise

        >>> today = dt.date.today()
        >>> within_days_from_today(today - dt.timedelta(days=1), num_days=3)
        False
        >>> within_days_from_today(dt.date.today(), num_days=3)
        True
        >>> within_days_from_today(today + dt.timedelta(days=1), num_days=3)
        True
        >>> within_days_from_today(today + dt.timedelta(days=2), num_days=3)
        True
        >>> within_days_from_today(today + dt.timedelta(days=3), num_days=3)
        True
        >>> within_days_from_today(today + dt.timedelta(days=4), num_days=3)
        False
    '''
    lower_limit = dt.date.today()
    upper_limit = lower_limit + dt.timedelta(days=num_days)
    if lower_limit <= the_date <= upper_limit:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I like this too. I like the support for lower and upper, as I may not want to count a days prior to today. Complete with doctest! ;)

Answer (score 8):

Object oriented solution

```
import datetime

class DatetimeRange:
    def __init__(self, dt1, dt2):
        self._dt1 = dt1
        self._dt2 = dt2

    def __contains__(self, dt):
        return self._dt1 < dt < self._dt2

dt1 = datetime.datetime.now()
dt2 = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(days = 2)
test_true = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
test_false = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(days = 5)

test_true in DatetimeRange(dt1, dt2) #Returns True
test_false in DatetimeRange(dt1, dt2) #Returns False
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I think range should be inclusive, so using lessorequal: <=

Answer (score 0):

convert elapsed time into days then apply a ternary operation to the days elapsed

```
current_dt=datetime.now()
feed_dt = datetime.now()-timedelta(days=3)
from_dt=datetime(year=feed_dt.year,month=feed_dt.month,day=feed_dt.day)
days_elapsed=(current_dt-from_dt).days
print(True if days_elapsed <=3 else False)
```

Output:
True