# Unexpected input value detection for dates in Zodiac calendar sample

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a task in Python, which is to create a zodiac calendar judging by input month and day of the month.

I've made a successful calendar, however, I have no idea how to solve the problem, if I input an incorrect month name or nonexistent date.

I have tried tons of things: to create a different hierarchy, or under each zodiac sign I wrote `else: print ('Entering an incorrect date')`. I even tried to register with `if day <0 and day> 31 or month! = 'March' or month! = 'April'`, etc... It turned out to be a huge useless function in the end, and nothing worked either.

I feel that there is a one-line solution here to detect days < 0 and > 31 and incorrect month name, but I just can't understand it. Could somebody help, please?

```
month = input('Enter the month: ')
day = int(input ('Enter the date of month: '))
if day >= 21 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'march' or day >=1 and day <= 19 and month.lower() == 'april':
    zodiac='Aries'
if day >= 20 and day <= 30 and month.lower() == 'april' or day >=1 and day <= 19 and month.lower() == 'may':
    zodiac='Taurus'
if day >= 21 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'may' or day >=1 and day <= 20 and month.lower() == 'june':
    zodiac='Gemini'
if day >= 21 and day <= 30 and month.lower() == 'june' or day >=1 and day <= 22 and month.lower() == 'july':
    zodiac='Cancer'
if day >= 23 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'july' or day >=1 and day <= 22 and month.lower() == 'august':
    zodiac='Leo'
if day >= 23 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'august' or day >=1 and day <= 22 and month.lower() == 'september':
    zodiac='Virgo'
if day >= 23 and day <= 30 and month.lower() == 'september' or day >=1 and day <= 22 and month.lower() == 'october':
    zodiac='Libra'
if day >= 23 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'october' or day >=1 and day <= 21 and month.lower() == 'november':
    zodiac='Scorpio'
if day >= 22 and day <= 30 and month.lower() == 'november' or day >=1 and day <= 21 and month.lower() == 'december':
    zodiac='Sagittarius'
if day >= 22 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'december' or day >=1 and day <= 19 and month.lower() == 'january':
    zodiac='Capricorn'
if day >= 20 and day <= 31 and month.lower() == 'january' or day >=1 and day <= 18 and month.lower() == 'february':
    zodiac='Aquarius'
if day >= 19 and day <= 28 and month.lower() == 'february' or day >=1 and day <= 20 and month.lower() == 'march':
    zodiac='Pisces'  
print('Conclusion:')
print(zodiac)
```

Comment: What was the problem with `else: print(...)`?

Comment: You should try the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module from the standard library. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695609/checking-date-against-date-range-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. With it, you can do comparisons between dates and times easily without the need for extraneous if statements.

For example, if one were to do something like:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
print dt.month
```

Then you would get:

```
3
```

So instead of reading in input for months in a string format, you could simply ask for the number of the month to help create a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object more easily. Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
month_input = input("What is the month?")
months = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]
month_input = month_input.lower().strip() #convert to lowercase and remove whitespace
month_num = months.index(month_input) + 1 #Add one because lists start at index 0
```

That way you can get the number of the month to use a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object to do your comparisons and evaluations from there.